# How can I switch to my onboard audio controller?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

My desktop (running Arch) has a (very, very) old SB Live! sound card that isn't working very well any more. I'd like to switch to using the motherboard's onboard audio controller instead. Sadly, `pavucontrol` and my DE's (Cinnamon) settings both only see the SB Live card (click for larger versions):

[image: pavucontrol screenshot]

[image: Cinnamon audio settings]

However, `inxi` shows that the onboard card is recognized and has a driver assigned:

```
$ inxi -A
Audio:     Card-1 Intel NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Creative Labs SB Live! EMU10k1 driver: snd_emu10k1
           Card-3 Logitech Webcam C210 driver: USB Audio
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.2.5-1-ARCH
```

The driver module is indeed loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_intel          32768  9
snd_hda_codec         106496  3 snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           49152  4 snd_hda_codec_via,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_pcm                86016  11 snd_usb_audio,snd_ac97_codec,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_emu10k1,snd_hda_core
snd                    65536  41 snd_usb_audio,snd_ac97_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_via,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_emu10k1,snd_seq_device
```

On the off chance that the onboard card was being blocked by the SB Live!, I blacklisted the SB's driver:

```
$ echo 'blacklist snd_emu10k1' | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/snd_emu10k1.conf
```

After rebooting, `inxi` showed:

```
$ inxi -A
Audio:     Card-1 Intel NM10/ICH7 Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-3 Logitech Webcam C210 driver: USB Audio
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.2.5-1-ARCH
```

And the SB Live! was no longer visible in `pavucontrol` or Cinnamon's settings but neither was the onboard card. It only showed the HDMI port from the screenshots above.

So, how can I get my system to use the onboard audio card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Automatically load cards using udev

The pulseaudio module responsible for automatically loading a sound card recognized by ALSA is `module-udev-detect` on sytems supporting udev. This module should be loaded on starting the pulseaudio with the `default.pa` which usually is located in `/etc/pulse/`.

To see whether this module is loaded we can issue:

```
pactl list short modules
```

If there is no `module-udev-detect` present we can load and test it by running

```
pactl load-module module-udev-detect
```

Any ALSA card present in the system should then be loaded as an output sink selectable from sound settings or seen with

```
pactl list short cards
```

On success the following lines can be added to our `default.pa`:

```
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
load-module module-udev-detect
.else
load-module module-detect
.endif
```

The `module-detect` may detect cards on a system where udev is not supported.

#### Manually load an ALSA card

If that failed we can also manually load an ALSA card with the following command:

```
pactl load-module module-alsa-card <options>
```

The `<options>` field depends on our hardware. In below example

```
device_id="0" name="pci-0000_00_05.0" card_name="alsa_card.pci-0000_00_05.0" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes
```

- **`device_id`** is the card number as given with

  ```
    aplay -l
  ```
- **`name`** is a name we can freely choose
- **`card_name`** is the name defined by ALSA as listed on

  ```
    ls /dev/snd/by-path
  ```
- other options are defaults for a standard card.

Again, on success we can add this to our `/etc/pulse/default.pa` for loading every time the sound server starts.

```
load-module module-alsa-card <options>
```

Comment: Well, it seems I did something wrong :). I'd appreciate your input on [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253028/22222) if/when you have the time.