# Problems with pulseaudio - pavucontrol and pacmd not connecting to pulseaudio

Tags: debian, pulseaudio

I'm running Debian Jessie (8.3) with the following `pulseaudio` packages. As far as I know all sound related stuff (including `pulseaudio`) corresponds to the default Jessie packages. I have not customized anything. Nor have I done anything with `systemd`, which I know nothing about.

```
dpkg -l | grep pulseaudio
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64    1.4.4-2               amd64                 GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  pulseaudio                       5.0-13                amd64                 PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-esound-compat         5.0-13                amd64                 PulseAudio ESD compatibility layer
ii  pulseaudio-module-gconf          5.0-13                amd64                 GConf module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-x11            5.0-13                amd64                 X11 module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-utils                 5.0-13                amd64                 Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
```

I just replaced my old Sound Blaster Live! card with a newer Asus Xonar DX card. The sound works, but the mike doesn't. Additionally, I have problems with pulseaudio. The pulseaudio problems (at least in part) precede the replacement of the card, but I think I need to solve them first, before figuring out the mike issue. So, this question is just about the Pulseaudio issues.

Till I rebooted today after the reinstallation of the new sound card, `pavucontrol` was working, at least, though `pacmd` has been erroring out for some time.

This appears in part to be some kind of permission issue, but I don't know what. I've not made any manual changes to `pulseaudio` or anything else sound related, aside from adding my user to both the `pulse` and `pulse-connect` groups. I didn't think it would make any difference, and I haven't noticed any.

I'm adding the output from various commands below to illustrate the problem, both as root and user. Commands preceded by`$` represent commands run by the user, and commands preceded by `#` represent commands run by root, as per standard convention.

```
$ pulseaudio -vv
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NICE, (31, 31)) failed: Operation not permitted
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: setrlimit(RLIMIT_RTPRIO, (9, 9)) failed: Operation not permitted
D: [pulseaudio] core-rtclock.c: Timer slack is set to 50 us.
D: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: RealtimeKit worked.
I: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Successfully gained nice level -11.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: This is PulseAudio 5.0
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation host: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compilation CFLAGS: -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -W -Wextra -pipe -Wno-long-long -Wno-overlength-strings -Wunsafe-loop-optimizations -Wundef -Wformat=2 -Wlogical-op -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wformat-nonliteral -Wpointer-arith -Winit-self -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wfloat-equal -Wmissing-prototypes -Wredundant-decls -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-noreturn -Wshadow -Wendif-labels -Wcast-align -Wstrict-aliasing -Wwrite-strings -Wno-unused-parameter -ffast-math -fno-common -fdiagnostics-show-option
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running on host: Linux x86_64 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u3 (2016-01-17)
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Found 6 CPUs.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Page size is 4096 bytes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Compiled with Valgrind support: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in valgrind mode: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Running in VM: no
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: Optimized build: yes
D: [pulseaudio] main.c: FASTPATH defined, only fast path asserts disabled.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Machine ID is 501a8b6f724c87677a6f6bb351f93f66.
I: [pulseaudio] main.c: Session ID is 55.
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
```

The output as root for this command was the same.

```
$ pacmd
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon

# pacmd
Daemon not responding.
```

Pavucontrol gives (first, on the terminal)

```
$ pavucontrol 
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
Failed to create secure directory (/run/user/1000/pulse): Permission denied
```

And the following box pops up. (This graphic was swiped from terdon's [Pulseaudio broken on Arch: pa_stream_writable_size() failed: Connection terminated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253028/4671), since it's exactly the same as what I see.)
[image: Pavucontrol popup box display]

On root

```
# pavucontrol 

[A popup box appears with]
Establishing connection to PulseAudio. Please wait.
```

`find` doesn't find any hits for "ulse" in the `~/.config` directory.

```
~/.config$ find . -name '*ulse*'
```

returns nothing.

`Pulseaudio` appears to be running

```
# ps aux | grep pulse
faheem    5057  0.1  0.0 376208 10432 ?        S<l  13:54   0:35 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
faheem    5065  0.0  0.0 122904  5164 ?        S    13:54   0:00 /usr/lib/pulseaudio/pulse/gconf-helper
```

as does `systemd`.

```
# ps aux | grep systemd
root       273  0.0  0.0  33092  6864 ?        Ss   13:50   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       290  0.0  0.0  41644  3864 ?        Ss   13:50   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root      1067  0.0  0.0  28268  2968 ?        Ss   13:50   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
message+  1100  0.0  0.0  43160  4432 ?        Ss   13:50   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
faheem    4435  0.0  0.0  36432  4544 ?        Ss   13:51   0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

The permissions of the files in `/run/user/1000/pulse` are:

```
/run/user/1000/pulse# ls -laR
.:
total 4
drwx------ 2 root   root    80 Feb 22 13:54 .
drwx------ 6 faheem faheem 120 Feb 22 13:54 ..
srwxrwxrwx 1 faheem faheem   0 Feb 22 13:54 native
-rw------- 1 faheem faheem   5 Feb 22 13:54 pid
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Looks like `systemd-logind` isn't being used. Are you logging in through a DM like `GDM`?

Comment: @jordanm Debian jessie (8.3). I'm using KDE. What doess `systemd-logind` do?

Comment: `/run/user/1000/pulse` should be user owned (uid 1000 or faheem). Did you tried to start pulseaudio with root permissions?

Comment: @Braiam generally pulse is started per-user, not as root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem appears to have been caused by running some `Pulseaudio` command as root. This apparently changed the permissions in `/run/user/1000/pulse`. Rebooting fixed the issue.

These are now

```
$ ls  -lah /run/user/1000/pulse/
total 4.0K
drwx------ 2 faheem faheem 100 Feb 22 21:50 .
drwx------ 6 faheem faheem 120 Feb 22 21:41 ..
srwxrwxrwx 1 faheem faheem   0 Feb 22 21:50 cli
srwxrwxrwx 1 faheem faheem   0 Feb 22 21:41 native
-rw------- 1 faheem faheem   5 Feb 22 21:41 pid
```

Note the difference from the result that appears in my question:

```
/run/user/1000/pulse# ls -laR
.:
total 4
drwx------ 2 root   root    80 Feb 22 13:54 .
drwx------ 6 faheem faheem 120 Feb 22 13:54 ..
srwxrwxrwx 1 faheem faheem   0 Feb 22 13:54 native
-rw------- 1 faheem faheem   5 Feb 22 13:54 pid
```

I.e. `/run/user/1000/pulse` is owned by root there.

But if this is broken so easily, it seems overly fragile.