# Grant full root permissions to an user

Tags: permissions, users, root

In `/etc/sudoers` I added:
`%myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Now if I type `sudo apt update` I don' t need to type the password.
But I want full root permissions: namely, I want to use only `apt update`.
The apt is an example i want FULL ROOT PERMISSIONS, another example is to be able to create/modify files everywhere.

I tried to use the root line (`root ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`) in the myuser line but nothing:
`%myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

This is my `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
scorpion  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d

%scorpion ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Comment: When you start a new shell session, you can just type `sudo su -` and you will become `root` and not have to use `sudo`.

Comment: It's bad practice to modify the root line in the `sudoers` file.  Please undo the edit, and see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The more secure way to run `apt update` with `root` privileges, **without** typing `sudo apt update`, would be to add an alias for `apt` to your user's profile:

- `alias apt='sudo apt'`

Then, whenever you run `apt update`, or `apt upgrade`, or `apt install <pkg>`, the apt command will be run with root privileges.  But other commands will just run as your normal user, with normal user privileges.

---

Now, Acknowledging that there are valid reasons why we don't just run all users with root permissions, the following is a way you can give a user all the same permissions as root, that doesn't use sudo.

- Change the user's UID and GID to 0 with `usermod -ou 0 -g 0 <username>`

This will change everything your `<username>` user does to run with root permissions.  Everything.

**Yes.  I know this is massively insecure.**   But, it *does* answer the question.

If you choose this route, please do it on a system you don't mind re-installing from time to time.  Running everything as root can end up having unforeseen consequences.

Comment: The `usermod` suggestion is the permanent solution the OP is asking for, hence the upvote. I will expect another question soon on how to recover the system after an accidental oops.

Comment: Everyone has to learn sometime.  When I first started using Linux, I must have reinstalled my system almost daily, from screwing something up.  Fixing screwups is really a great way to learn. :)

Comment: I have told my staff multiple times that you're not a real sysadmin until you have totally destroyed at least one system, often a production server. :)

Comment: hahaha... that's so true! :D

Comment: I already reinstalled the system some times :) now i ' m gonna try the `usermod -ou 0 -g 0 <username>` change only the UID (as told me before) is a bad idea. The apt is an example i want all root permission, so i can create/modify files everywhere.

Comment: I change both but i have the same problem this is my terminal: `I have no name!@my-pc`. I cannot use sudo or su. The root user is not allowed to log in in my system. I' m switching to Debian now i' m on Ubuntu. I already know how to fix it.

Comment: I will try on Debian on my other pc if works there

Comment: Is working on Debian so i have to change both UID and GID?

Comment: After reboot i can' t login. If i use passwd scorpion: user not exist. So i set as before the UID and GID, i tried to change the password but passwd: Authentication token manipulation error passwd: password unchanged. When i  log in i get wrong password.

Comment: Anyway change the user's UID and GID to 0 is a bad idea. It will break the user. 0 is the root UID and GID so another user can' t have it. Indeed when i changed them before the reboot i saw root@debian-pc when i launched a normal terminal.

Comment: @TimKennedy You should remove the part change the user's UID and GID to 0 because it will cause problems. If it would be like you said,  i will have the answer to my question but it isn' t so.

Comment: This doesn't cause an issue on systems where root isn't disabled.  See the [Debian Wiki: Root Account](https://wiki.debian.org/Root).  Note that option 2: *If not, no root account is enabled and the password of the first user created will be used for administration tasks.* is still the default on Ubuntu.  This was done to prevent the exact thing your question is asking us.  The first user account is added automatically at install.

Comment: @eyoung100 Did you read the update question (and this comments)? I can' t use the account anymore on Debian if i set UID and GID to 0.

Comment: When you set any account have a UID/GID of 0/0, you give that account root equivalency in all privileges and restrictions by *actually* making that account the equal of root in every meaningful way.  That is, the Effective GID/UID of every command that user runs is 0.  Which is what you asked for, which many people told you is a bad idea.  Now you have a better understanding of *why* people said it's a bad idea, and why so many sites on the internet advise against that kind of change.

Comment: @TimKennedy i know that i can break the system having full root permission, but if i change UID/GID to 0 the account will be immediately unusable.

Comment: Only root can have 0 and anyway an user can' t have the same UID then another right? The GID i don' t know.

Comment: you can create as many users as you want with the same UIDs and GIDs.  That's literally why the `useradd` command has the `-o, --non-unique` option.  Believe it or not, there are actually valid use cases for shared UIDs, generally pertaining to web and mail hosting, where the UIs that users use can use the username to distinguish users, but the mail or web system only needs 1 set of permissions to store mail or write files to document roots.  Linux won't protect you from doing something against your best interests, though, so you have to understand your use case.

Comment: @TimKennedy right is really possible to share the UID, but the 0 isn' t reserved to the root? That' s why the user will be broken and the terminal said (before reboot) `root@my-pc` or something.

Comment: It's reserved to whatever user the system finds first with that UID.  In fact, the UID is really the user, and the name is sort of arbitrary to the kernel.  Only in much higher level applications (like a mail server) does the name matter.  When you run `id` or `whoami`, on Linux, the system just reads the files and grabs the first name it finds with a matching UID.  If I create users with the same ID and use SSH to login, I have to use the password that matches the name, so sshd or PAM must be username aware.  Once I've logged in, though, `whoami` shows the first user whose UID matches.

Comment: @TimKennedy there is someone that is able to change the UID/GID to 0 and use the user? The only that i found  is this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271197/pulseaudio-run-as-root#autocomment865498. He said that he changed `user1:x:00:00:user1,,,:/home/user1:/bin/bash` so he set UID/GID to 00?

Comment: Can you tag me? Because i don' t receive a notification i have to check manually.

Comment: @Scorpion I can.  Now, since your UID is 0, you will have to enable root logins via SSH if  that's the problem you have.  in /etc/ssh/sshd_config: `PermitRootLogin yes`.  Once you login, `whoami` and `id` will show you logged in as root, because you have UID 0, and they just search the user/group databases (as configured in nsswitch.conf) for the first match, but if you look at what directory you're in, it should show you in the `/home/scorpion`.  Likeway, `passwd scorpion` will change the `scorpion` user password, but not the `root` password.

Comment: @TimKennedy as i said in the update question in debian and ubuntu the user became unusable. Luckily i already planned to reinstall debian (also was an almost new installation). So i give up and reinstalled debian and now is configured to use only the root. Because this question didn' t find an answer and is better if i directly use the root.

Comment: @Scorpion I'm using Ubuntu, and didn't have any problems related to it, other than ambiguous output by commands that just lookup the UID in the user (nsswitch) database.  You can always reset the UID/GID by manually editing `/etc/passwd`.  You may not be able to do with via `usermod` or `userdel` because the tools may complain about the user account being in use.

Comment: @TimKennedy you changed UID/GID to 0?

Comment: @Scorpion yes.  I did have to manually edit `/etc/passwd` when i was done, but I was able to ssh in as my alternate-uid-0 account.  `whoami` still showed `root` as the user I was logged in as, but that's due to root being the first matching name in /etc/passwd.  change the order in /etc/password, so that you're alternate user is above root, all the tools will show the `scorpion` name.  That's just a display feature though, not an actual systemic change.  Processes running as UID 0 will still run as UID 0 regardless of which name is displayed.

Comment: @TimKennedy only ssh or also "normal login" with your alternate-uid-0 account?

Comment: @Scorpion ahh.  `ssh`.  If you're getting locked out of normal logins, that is almost certainly because UID 0 has restrictions placed on which terminals they can log in to.  These are in the file `/etc/securetty`.   You'd need to add any tty's that you want your UID 0 `scorpion` user to be able to log into to that file.

Comment: @Scorpion all of this sort of goes back to the point that while Linux won't protect you from yourself, the distro maintainers have worked pretty hard to protect you from yourself, and working around these protections puts your system at risk.  I think it's important for sysadmins to really understand their systems, and why certain decisions are made, so that you can make good informed decisions about the best way to compromise between security and ease of use.

Comment: @TimKennedy exactly what i have to modify in the `securetty`? How i can add all the possible tty? Can you test it?

Comment: @Scorpion several ways.  individually add all possible entries to `/etc/securetty`; add wildcards such as `pts/[0-9]*` to `/etc/securetty`; remove the call to `pam_securetty.so` in `/etc/pam.conf`, or `/etc/pam.d/login`, etc.

Comment: @TimKennedy can you explain it better? Which are all possible entries? And the wildcards? Which call in `etc/pam.d/login`? There i can see `# Disallows root logins except on tty's listed in /etc/securetty
# (Replaces the `CONSOLE' setting from login.defs)`

Comment: @Scorpion there are too many possibilities to list them all in a comment here, especially given variations in hardware.  Much easier to just remove the file.  Basically, just do the opposite of everything in this article: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Security_Guide/s2-wstation-privileges-noroot.html

Answer (score 0):

You can type `sudo -i`, then you get an interactive root shell and don't have to type `sudo` before each command.

Comment: I want  a permanent solution.

Comment: Then place that command in the user's `.profile`. Or let the user login as root.

Comment: How can i let the user login as root?

Comment: I just set a password for root and can login as root. If your distribution disables root login, you should find out how it is done and undo it. Or at least mention what distribution you are using.

Comment: Right, but i don' t want to login as root i want the user to become a "second" root.

Comment: Then why do you ask how to do it? I already suggested placing the command into the user's `.profile`. If you also don't want that, then please edit the question and be very specific about what you really want.

Comment: The title isn' t clear? Using the `.profile' is almost good but if i created a folder later i won't be able to see it right? Btw when you said "Or let the user login as root." i though you mean that (Grant full root permissions to an user).

Comment: To make a user a "second" root, change their UID to 0 in /etc/passwd.

Answer (score 0):

Using Gentoo's `/etc/sudoers` file as a default, you have two options:

Option 1:

---

```
## sudoers file.
.. snip ..
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
## Add your user here.  This allows you to run all commands as root, 
## not just the update commands.
scorpion ALL=(ALL) ALL
.. snip ..
```

Option 2:

---

```
## sudoers file.
.. snip ..
## User alias specification
##
## Groups of users.  These may consist of user names, uids, Unix groups,
## or netgroups.
# User_Alias    ADMINS = millert, dowdy, mikef
User_Alias  UPDATERS = scorpion
##
## Cmnd alias specification
##
## Groups of commands.  Often used to group related commands together.
# Cmnd_Alias    PROCESSES = /usr/bin/nice, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/renice, \
#               /usr/bin/pkill, /usr/bin/top
# Cmnd_Alias    REBOOT = /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/poweroff
Cmnd_Alias  UPDATE = /path/to/apt-get, /path/to/apt
.. snip ..
##
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
UPDATERS ALL=NOPASSWD: UPDATE
```

---

### Notes

1. This example assumes your username is `scorpion`.
2. I assume the path to all the `apt` commands are in `/sbin` but Gentoo doesn't use `apt` or `apt-get` so don't forget to edit.
3. This can be done without adding Command Aliases, and User Aliases, but IMHO, the aliases make it easier to add commands, and to debug if needed.

Comment: Option is not working is similar to use the root line for my user. Option 2 is for apt only right? i want to grant full root permissions not only apt.

Comment: If you want full permission everywhere then add your user to the `sudo` group, aka wheel, and remove the comment on the line starting %sudo ALL = ALL... with the nopasswd option. It may read %wheel.  You cannot do what your asking, as sudo sets the proper permissions bit, and the UID/GID of 0 should always belong to root as @TimKennedy pointed out.

Comment: Follow @TimKennedy's answer, and set your UID and GID to zero, thereby replacing the root user with your user.  The reason it's "massively insecure" is because you have removed all safety measures.  See [What's wrong with always being root?](https://serverfault.com/questions/57962/whats-wrong-with-always-being-root)  Before I can advise you on the proper configuration, should you decide against Tim's answer I need to know what distribution you're using.

Comment: And did you read my comment in Tim's answer?  It breaks in all Debian and Debian relatives because Debian is designed to prevent what your asking.