# Sound doesn't work properly in root but does in normal user

Tags: debian, audio, root

I'm using debian 9 with gnome.
When i use the root the volume control doesn' t work and doesn' t have the megaphone symbol (that is also missing in the gnome panel). I can move the bar but doesn` t affect the volume.

[image]

In `Settings`/`Sound` there aren' t any output/input devices.
There aren't any system sounds like when you keep deleting in the terminal or when you using <kbd>fn</kbd> + the volume controls that aren' t working.
Fn keys are working for the others functions but not for the audio.
Except for the system sounds the audio is working and i can set the volume using `alsa-mixer` (that isn' t practical).

If i use a normal user everything is fine: the volume control (in the gnome panel) works and has the megaphone symbol, system sounds are working, fn keys for the audio are working and in `Settings`/`Sound` there are the output/input devices.

How can i have fix the audio for the root?

Don' t tell me that is dangerous and why i want log in as root.
I really wish to do so.
From the comments i can see that dirkt states:

> Pulseaudio by default only works with a logged-in user, by design

Any idea to how fix `pulseaudio`?

Comment: Why are you using desktop/audio as root?

Comment: Pulseaudio by default only works with a logged-in user, by design. Don't use a desktop as root, it's bad practice. Use `sudo` as normal user for system administration.

Comment: @dirkt i want to use root, there is a solution for pulseaudio?

Comment: The part about *how user aliases/renames root* is not relevant. The duplicate similarly asks about audio not working for root desktop. For allowing regular users access `/root` you can post another question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too bad that you didn' t know that all those problems are caused by `pulseaudio`.
If you run in a terminal `pulseaudio` you will see something like this:

```
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
```

If you run `pulseaudio --system` won' t work (at least on my system), I don' t know if there is any proper solution.
But there is a very simple and perfect workaround use only `pulseaudio`:

1. Copy this folder `/home/normal-user/.config/pulse` into your home
   (`/root/.config`) from another "normal" user.
2. In `/root/.config/autostart` (if the folder doesn't exist create it)
   make a file with this content:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Terminal=false
   OnlyShowIn=GNOME;KDE
   Exec=pulseaudio
   Name=pulseaudio
   Comment=Volume/audio controls
   ```
3. And name it `pulseaudio.desktop` (the important thing is the
   `.desktop`).
    Double click and you are ok (trust and launch).

   Now every time that you log in (as root) your sound will be fine.

Other GUIs:

It also works for KDE plasma.
If your GUI uses `pulseaudio` you can add it to the entry `OnlyShowIn=`.
Or remove that line to always start pulseaudio (on every GUI).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Should this work if I log into the desktop as a regular user, then `su` to root and start an audio application from the terminal?

Comment: @Time4Tea This works also on debian 10 gnome, when you login as root. On gnome by default you can' t, I modified the gnome config to allow root to login. If you login as regular user do you need to run audio applications as root?

Comment: I never tried it.

Comment: I would like to sandbox Skype and Steam with firejail, which requires root privileges to set up the sandbox. I am finding that sound is not working for firejailed applications with pulseaudio.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/574308/problems-with-sound-in-firejail