# Problems with sound in firejail

Tags: audio, root, pulseaudio, firejail

I am using Parabola (based on Arch) and I would like to use firejail to sandbox one or two less trusted applications (steam, in particular). However, when running applications in firejail (even with the --noprofile option, which is supposed to give the least-restrictive sandbox), I don't hear any sound. I have tried with steam and rhythmbox and have the same problem with both.

I have an open ticket [here](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/3282) on github. I am using pulseaudio and I suspect the issue may be similar as to why I also get no sound when I run the same applications from the terminal as the root user (because firejail itself needs superuser priviledges to setup the sandbox, before handing over to the jailed application).

Is there a way I can enable sound in pulseaudio for the root user, such that if I log in to the desktop as a regular user; `su` to root in the terminal; and then run rhythmbox, the sound will play? I am aware of this [existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473817/257802); however, it doesn't seem to work for me (presumably, this would only work if I were to log in to the entire desktop session as root, which I don't want to do).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question: I uninstalled pulseaudio and now the sound seems to work fine in the firejailed applications (presumably they are now using ALSA directly). I suspect the issue was because pulseaudio does not allow server access for the root user; however, firejail requires root privileges.

Comment: When I launch an application as another user I have to use this: ssh -XY <another_user>@localhost <package>   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108784/running-gui-application-as-another-non-root-user

Comment: @Scorpion the GUI windows open fine with the firejailed applications. It's the audio that's the problem.

Comment: Would be nice to know the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the apulse package?

> The program provides an alternative partial implementation of the
>   PulseAudio API. It consists of a loader script and a number of shared
>   libraries with the same names as from original PulseAudio, so
>   applications could dynamically load them and think they are talking to
>   PulseAudio. Internally, no separate sound mixing daemon is used.
>   Instead, apulse relies on ALSA's dmix, dsnoop, and plug plugins to
>   handle multiple sound sources and capture streams running at the same
>   time. dmix plugin muxes multiple playback streams; dsnoop plugin allow
>   multiple applications to capture from a single microphone; and plug
>   plugin transparently converts audio between various sample formats,
>   sample rates and channel numbers.

```
apulse <program>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, although I haven't tried that. For me, uninstalling pulseaudio resolved the issue and doesn't seem to have caused any other problems. So, I haven't seen much need to try anything else.