# Microphone not working on archlinux

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa

#### Context

I have been running `archlinux` on my laptop for years and never needed the microphone.  Now I need it but cannot find a way to configure it properly.

I use `alsa` and `pulseadio`.

Running `alsamixer` as a user I have two gauges:

```
  ||      ||
Master  Capture
```

I have both of them unmuted and enabled to sensible (~50%) values.

Running `alsamixer` as root I have several gauges:

```
  ||        ||        ||      ||      ||       ||
Master  Headphones  Speaker  PCM  Microphone MIC Boot 

 ||      ||       ||        ||       ||
Beep  Loopback Internal  Internal  Capture
```

If I enable the `Loopback` as root **I can hear the microphone back through the speakers**.

If I explicitly select my sound card in `alsamixer` as a user I get the same commands as running as root (and if I enable `Loopback` here I do hear the microphone from the speakers as well).  I get the following:

[image]

(To the right are two more `Internal` gauges, the `Loopback` (enable/disable) and a mutable `Off-hook`)

Yet, no matter what I do and how much I meddle with the alsa gauges I never manage to pass the microphone to the user application.  In essence, every time I run `arecord` I get the following output:

```
$ arecord -vv -f dat /dev/null 
Recording WAVE '/dev/null' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 48000 Hz, Stereo
ALSA <-> PulseAudio PCM I/O Plugin
Its setup is:
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 48000
  exact rate   : 48000 (48000/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 24000
  period_size  : 6000
  period_time  : 125000
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : GETTIMEOFDAY
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 6000
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 24000
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 6755399441055744000
#+                                                 | 00%
```

`aplay`, on the other hand, works perfectly.

---

My sound card is (`lspci`):

```
# lspci| grep -i audio
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
```

I looked at the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture/Troubleshooting#Microphone) and tried setting the following in `/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf` (and rebooted the machine):

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-m6-dmic
```

(I cannot get the microphone to send data to the user application with or without that configuration.)

My current `hda` modules are:

```
# lsmod |grep hda
snd_hda_codec_si3054    16384  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek    69632  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          32768  5
snd_hda_codec         106496  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           61440  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                86016  4 snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd                    65536  18 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_si3054,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
```

For completeness, this is my `pulseaudio` config (I have not tried meddling with it):

```
$ pulseaudio --dump-conf
### Read from configuration file: /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ###
daemonize = no
fail = yes
high-priority = yes
nice-level = -11
realtime-scheduling = yes
realtime-priority = 5
allow-module-loading = yes
allow-exit = yes
use-pid-file = yes
system-instance = no
local-server-type = user
cpu-limit = no
enable-shm = yes
flat-volumes = no
lock-memory = no
exit-idle-time = 20
scache-idle-time = 20
dl-search-path = /usr/lib/pulse-9.0/modules
default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-default-script-file = yes
log-target = 
log-level = notice
resample-method = auto
enable-remixing = yes
enable-lfe-remixing = no
lfe-crossover-freq = 0
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 44100
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
default-sample-channels = 2
default-channel-map = front-left,front-right
default-fragments = 4
default-fragment-size-msec = 25
enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 8000
deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
shm-size-bytes = 0
log-meta = no
log-time = no
log-backtrace = 0
rlimit-fsize = -1
rlimit-data = -1
rlimit-stack = -1
rlimit-core = -1
rlimit-rss = -1
rlimit-as = -1
rlimit-nproc = -1
rlimit-nofile = 256
rlimit-memlock = -1
rlimit-locks = -1
rlimit-sigpending = -1
rlimit-msgqueue = -1
rlimit-nice = 31
rlimit-rtprio = 9
rlimit-rttime = 200000
```

As per Faheem Mitha's comment, I'm confident the `pulseaudio` `tmpfs` has the right permissions:

```
# ls -la /run/user/861213/pulse/
total 4
drwx------ 2 grochmal users  80 Jul  4 21:44 .
drwx------ 5 grochmal users 120 Jul  4 21:46 ..
srw-rw-rw- 1 grochmal users   0 Jul  4 21:44 native
-rw------- 1 grochmal users   4 Jul  4 21:44 pid
```

And `pavucontrol` was muted.  I was not aware of `pavucontrol` which resulted in the issue in the first place:

[image]

---

#### Question

I'm out of ideas.  I *believe* that the `Loopback` audio interface exists in *kernel space*, therefore my problem is that I cannot bring the microphone data into *user space*.  Yet, I'm not 100% sure of it.

What other options can I give to `snd-hda-intel` (or the other modules) that might be relevant for a microphone that works on the loopback interface but does not propagate to the application layer?

Could I be doing something wrong with `pulseaudio`?  But then again, `pulseaudio` worked correctly (together with `alsa`) for all that time, and I use `audacity` quite often.

Comment: Hi. You don't want to run alsamixer as root; you'll screw up your permissions. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265043/.  Can you provide a screenshot of alsamixer running as user? Make sure you select your sound card.

Comment: Unmute everything, and bring everything up to the maximum in `alsamixer`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - Thanks, I do get all gauges if i explicitly select the sound card in `alsamixer`.  For now I added the screenshot and confirmed my `pulseaudio` permissions (I even rebooted the machine to ensure that my meddling as root did not affect something).  Now I'm trying to play more with `pulseaudio`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - Unmuted everything, even `Beep`.  No joy.

Comment: What are your mike settings inside `pavucontrol`? And does the gauge wiggle when you talk into your mike? One long shot is that your machine is using another mike jack than the one you think it is using. I think @derobert was discussing this with some other user a while back. Maybe he can shed some light.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - Heh, it was muted inside `pavucontrol`.  That solves it.  I really wonder how this happened, i have another machine using the exact same Intel HDA module, same OS (with the same updates), same alsa and same pulseaudio; and it was not muted in there.  Before your comment `pavucontrol` was not installed on neither of the two machines (archlinux has `pavucontrol` as a separate package).

Comment: Pavucontrol just exposes the internal state. But if you want to know what that internal state is, you'll have to talk to someone who actually knows something about Pulseaudio and friends.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on correspondence with the poster (see comments), it turned out that the sound card was muted inside `pavucontrol`.

Comment: +1 Had the same issue, Open `pavucontrol` and click the right arrow until the "Input Devices" tab is highlighted, then click the volume icon (Mute Audio) which for me was activated by default.

Comment: I should probably add that I'm using GNOME 3 and only now just noticed there is a mute toggle in the sound settings which can also be used (no need for `pavucontrol`).

Answer (score 2):

I also met the problem of my microphone not working on Arch Linux. 
In my case there's no device shown under "Input Devices" in `pavucontrol`
(it says "no input devices available"). 
Following the following advice from Arch Wiki fixed it for me:

1. Run `arecord -l` to find out the id of the microphone
   in `hw:CARD,DEVICE` notation, e.g., if the output is

   ```
   **** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
   card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog[ALC269VC Analog]
   Subdevices: 1/1
   Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
   ```

   then the id is `hw:0,0`
2. Add the line

   ```
   load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,0
   ```

   (specifying your device id) in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`, somewhere before the

   ```
   .ifexists module-udev-detect.so
   ```

   line.
3. Run `pulseaudio -k; pulseaudio -D`
   to restart PulseAudio and activate the changes.

From [PulseAudio/Troubleshooting – Microphone not detected by PulseAudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone_not_detected_by_PulseAudio)
in the ArchWiki.

Comment: A bit late, but in such cases it can be useful to link to the original source.

Comment: [source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone_not_detected_by_PulseAudio)

Answer (score 1):

This link sorted me out: [Microphone not detected by PulseAudio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Microphone_not_detected_by_PulseAudio)

Determine the card and device number of your mic:

```
$ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
In hw:CARD,DEVICE notation, you would specify the above device as hw:0,0.
```

Then, edit /etc/pulse/default.pa and insert a load-module line specifying your device as follows:

```
load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,0
# the line above should be somewhere before the line below
.ifexists module-udev-detect.so
```

Finally, restart pulseaudio to apply the new settings:

```
$ pulseaudio -k ; pulseaudio -D
```

If everything worked correctly, you should now see your mic show up when running pavucontrol (under the Input Devices tab).

Answer (score 0):

1.rm -rf ~/.config/pulse

2.rm -rf /etc/pulse/

3.Plug in the usb headphone into laptop

4.pacman -S pulseaudio pavucontrol

5. Add "load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1" in /etc/pulse/default.pa

6.reboot

6.pavucontrol

OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and found that my USB microphone was only showing up in the "Configuration" tab of pavucontrol.  In order to get it to show up under the "Input Devices" tab, I had to change its configuration to "Multichannel Input".

At which point in order to record with it in Kdenlive, I needed to to change the built-in microphone to be muted (in pavucontrol) and click on the "Set as fallback" button on my USB microphone.

Side note that doing this allowed Kdenlive to use the default (`default:`) audio microphone.